# How to remove letters from the Y-axis in the echarts chart?

Tags: javascript, echarts

How can I remove letters from the Y-axis in the echarts ThemeRiver chart?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkG9S.jpg)

Comment: Please provide your code, on a TEXT basis, so that we can reproduce your example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can read the docs in the echarts [here](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#title)

but this is whats you looking for:

```
yAxis: [
        {
            show: false
        }
    ],
```